# Show other background image once block is hovered

Tags: css, hover, css-transforms, skew

I've 5 rows which are skewed.

Three of them should reveal a non-skewed backgound image with a link once hovered.

At this moment there are a few issues with this realization:

**1).** Once the mouse cursor is over the text block or Font Awesome icon - the background image hides out. This is natural, cause the text block is above the clickable area, but I haven't found a good solution to fix it.

**2).** Minor issue - the revealed background image and text block's items are skewed. They should be straight without an applied transformation.

The working example [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsewh7qv/)

**Markup:**

```
<div class="oblique-block">

   <a href="#" title="Meet the creators" target="_self">
       <div class="oblique first">
          <span class="fa fa-users fa-inverse fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">Meet <br /> us</span>
       </div>   
   </a>

   <a href="#" title="Cars that found homes" target="_self">
       <div class="oblique">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/365x458" />
          <span class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">Lorem <br /> ipsum</span>
       </div>
   </a>


   <a href="#" title="Check out the “a”list" target="_self">
       <div class="oblique">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/365x458" />
          <span class="fa fa-heart-o" fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">Check the <br /> lorem ipsum</span>
       </div>
   </a>

   <a href="#" title="Dipsum" target="_self">
       <div class="oblique">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/365x458" />
          <span class="fa fa-map-o fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">ipsum <br /> loremipsum</span>
       </div>
   </a>

   <a href="#" title="Get in touch with us" target="_self">
       <div class="oblique last">
          <span class="fa fa-comment-o fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">Get in touch <br /> with us</span>
       </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.oblique img {  
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);  
  height: 100%;  
  z-index: 100;
}

.oblique img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);  
}

.oblique img:hover ~ .oblique{z-index:-100!important;display:none!important!;}


.oblique-block {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.oblique {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.oblique-block > a:nth-child(even) > div:nth-child(1) {  
  background: #E0AE51;
}

.oblique-block > a:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #65C7CC;
}

.oblique.last {  
  background: #65C7CC;  
}
.oblique.last:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #65C7CC;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
  right: -30%;
}
.oblique.first:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #65C7CC;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
  right: 40%;
}

.oblique .fa{
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: normal; 
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
}

.oblique .fa-text{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);   
}

.oblique.last .fa-text{z-index:5;}
```

**layout**:
above is layout without hover effect, below with a hover effect
[image]

**UPD:** With Oliver's solution I've achieved the goal. But one issue left: the Font Awesome, text and revealed picture is skewed whereas they should be straight.

**UPD2** Solved by applying multiple transform `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skewx(10deg);`

Comment: How does it look if you move the hover element to the oblique class - that way it encompasses all of the children elements? `.oblique:hover img {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);  
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've managed to do what you were hoping for. The following CSS has been added, it is all commented so should explain the purpose. Let me know if you wanted something else.

```
// Hide anything that extends beyond the oblique element
.oblique {
  overflow: hidden;
}

// Move hover to the parent oblique so we capture all child elements (i.e. if they hover over the text)
.oblique:hover img {

  // No changes here
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);

  // Add a transformation to correct for the transformation of the parent oblique
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg); 
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);


  // Move the image a little to the left so that we don't get a gap from the transformation
  margin-left: -10px;

}
```

---

## Demo

```css
.oblique img {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.oblique {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.oblique:hover img {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.oblique img:hover~.oblique {
  z-index: -100!important;
  display: none!important!;
}

.oblique-block {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.oblique {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3498db;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform: skewx(-10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.oblique-block>a:nth-child(even)>div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #E0AE51;
}

.oblique-block>a:nth-child(odd)>div:nth-child(1) {
  background: #65C7CC;
}

.oblique.last {
  background: #65C7CC;
}

.oblique.last:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #65C7CC;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
  right: -30%;
}

.oblique.first:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #65C7CC;
  -webkit-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -o-transform: skewx(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform: skewx(10deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: relative;
  right: 40%;
}

.oblique .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
}

.oblique .fa-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.oblique.last .fa-text {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1eff64076c.js"></script>

<div class="oblique-block">

  <a href="#" title="Meet the creators" target="_self">
    <div class="oblique first">
      <span class="fa fa-users fa-inverse fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">Meet <br /> us</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#" title="Cars that found homes" target="_self">
    <div class="oblique">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" />
      <span class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="fa-text text-uppercase">Lorem <br /> ipsum</span>
    </div>
  </a>


  <a href="#" title="Check out the “a”list" target="_self">
    <div class="oblique">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" />
      <span class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3 " aria-hidden="true ">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="fa-text text-uppercase ">Check the <br /> lorem ipsum</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="# " title="Dipsum " target="_self ">
    <div class="oblique ">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" />
      <span class="fa fa-map-o fa-3 " aria-hidden="true ">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="fa-text text-uppercase ">ipsum <br /> loremipsum</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="# " title="Get in touch with us " target="_self ">
    <div class="oblique last ">
      <span class="fa fa-comment-o fa-3 " aria-hidden="true ">&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="fa-text text-uppercase ">Get in touch <br /> with us</span>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>

<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I've uploaded a picture to demonstrate, what I want to achieve. On hover the text should remain. I've found two little flaws: the left and right corners are skewed, while they also should remain straight regardless of device resolution. And the text data should not be skwed.